# How to limit the maximum length of a tmux window name?

Tags: tmux

I constantly use tmux to access a large number of VMs. In my configuration, I allowed window auto-renaming, and each window's name will be like

`Window# : Ssh-session : PATH`.

My status bar is like :

```
left-status | 1.window-name1  ...  2.window-name2 | right status
```

I am satisfied with the window name's format, but sometimes the window's name can be really long, and the entire status bar will be occupied by a single window, which looks like:

```
left-status | 1.root@AAAAAAAAJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ:/root/ 2.. | right status
```

Is there any way to constrain each window's name to a maximum length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man 1 tmux`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#OPTIONS):

> `automatic-rename-format format`
>   The format (see FORMATS) used when the `automatic-rename` option is enabled.

And then under [FORMATS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS):

> A limit may be placed on the length of the resultant string by prefixing it by an `=`, a number and a colon. Positive numbers count from the start of the string and negative from the end, so `#{=5:pane_title}` will include at most the first 5 characters of the pane title, or `#{=-5:pane_title}` the last 5 characters. [...]

So whatever your `format` is, you should rebuild it using this `#{=N:foo}` syntax.